# Jquery rating/liking script with tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've created a simple script that is supposed to provide a rating for specific elements. It's based on thumbs up/down. My code works ok mostly, but I am unable to:

1. Make the code cleaner
2. Remove the `active` class from an already clicked element (so it's a scenario when a thumb is either green/red and after clicking that color thumb it will become neutral; TL;DR it's about removing the solid fill and the active class)

```js
$('.like').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.like-active').removeClass('like-active');
  $('.dislike-active').removeClass('dislike-active');
  $('.like .fa-regular').toggleClass('fa-solid').removeClass('fa-regular');
  $('.dislike .fa-solid').toggleClass('fa-regular').removeClass('fa-solid');
  $(this).toggleClass('like-active');
  $(".like").not(this).removeClass("like-active");
});

$('.dislike').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.dislike-active').removeClass('like-active');
  $('.like-active').removeClass('like-active');
  $('.dislike .fa-regular').addClass('fa-solid').removeClass('fa-regular');
  $('.like .fa-solid').addClass('fa-regular').removeClass('fa-solid');
  $(this).toggleClass('dislike-active');
  $(".like").not(this).removeClass("dislike-active");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.rating {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
}

.like,
.dislike {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dislike:hover,
.like:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.like:hover {
  color: #349837;
}

.dislike:hover {
  color: #D82D05;
}

.like-active {
  color: #349837;
}

.dislike-active {
  color: #D82D05;
}

.tooltip {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.like:hover~.t-like {
  display: block;
}

.dislike:hover~.t-dislike {
  display: block;
}

.t-like,
.t-dislike {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="rating">
  <div class="like grow">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up fa-3x like" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="dislike grow">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-down fa-3x dislike" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <span class="tooltip t-like">Yay</span>
  <span class="tooltip t-dislike">Nay</span>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nc387bhr/3/)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Neither the snippet here, nor your jsfiddle, actually show _anything_ for me.

Comment: because this component will show when you hover on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve both of your goals, tidying the code and allowing the state of the vote to be toggled, by using a single class on both options. This class will control the state of the selection. You can also use this logic to set the `fa-solid` class on the chosen rating to change its appearance.

Here's a working example. Note that I changed the default state of the `.rating` container to be `opacity: 0.25` instead of hidden to make the behaviour clearer.

```js
$('.rating .option').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const $target = $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('active');
  $target.find('i').toggleClass('fa-solid');
  
  $('.active').not($target)
    .removeClass('active fa-solid')
    .find('i').removeClass('fa-solid');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.rating {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.25;
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;
}

.like,
.dislike {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dislike:hover,
.like:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.like:hover {
  color: #349837;
}

.dislike:hover {
  color: #D82D05;
}

.like.active {
  color: #349837;
}

.dislike.active {
  color: #D82D05;
}

.tooltip {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.like:hover~.t-like {
  display: block;
}

.dislike:hover~.t-dislike {
  display: block;
}

.t-like,
.t-dislike {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="rating">
  <div class="like grow option">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up fa-3x like" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="dislike grow option">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-down fa-3x dislike" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <span class="tooltip t-like">Yay</span>
  <span class="tooltip t-dislike">Nay</span>
</div>
```

As a side note, ensure you always use the event object passed to the event handlers as an argument, not the global event object. This is because the latter may not be available in all browsers, or may not be the event you expect it to be if multiple occur in a short time span.